# Installing IE 8 on windows xp hangs forever

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am attempting to install IE 8 on windows xp in a VM. It just hangs and says "Downloading" It has been like this for over an hour and I have an Internet connection that is fast.

[image: Windows XP IE 8 Upgrade screen]

I got Process Explorer and here are the results:

[image: Process Explorer]

[image: Process Explorer]

Comment: Was this installed by itself, or along with other updates?  Did you tried stopping it, rebooting and starting it again?  What actions _have_ you tried already?

Comment: It is just by itself. I have tried re-downloading and only choosing IE 8 from this page:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-8-details.aspx

Comment: When it's in this state, does Windows report any actual network and/or disk activity?  Does the IE installer show any CPU usage?

Comment: No cpu and no network activity. One thing that is odd is scvhost is at 99% cpu usage.

Comment: Grab Process Explorer from MS and figure out which service(s) are causing the Svchost to be that busy.

Comment: I got process explorer and posted the results above.

Answer (score 0):

The portion that's taking all the time is the installer checking Windows Update for updates. On XP systems, it's not uncommon to see this process take upwards of an hour. Let it sit and it will finish eventually.

Comment: It is going in 3 hours now, still hanging

Comment: Yikes. System specs? Had it been updating successfully before?

Comment: I updated to service pack 3 with no problem. This is a brand new Windows XP Installation. The only reason I am installing it is to test IE 8.

Comment: I am on mac book Air with 8 GB of Ram. I allocated 1 gb of ram to the VM. It boots in about 5 seconds. XP Is a great operating system to tell you the truth, but I just need to get IE 8 to work for testing.

Comment: Run the IE setup with the `/update-no` command line option to keep it from looking for updates.  Then do Windows Update later.

Answer (score 0):

Just disconnect your internet - it will take about 30secs to move past this point to scanning for malicious software.  Chances are it can't connect to windows update since XP has been put out of support past Sep 2014